# Is there a find/replace names

Tags: import

I imported a model via FBX and I want to delete all the prefixes added including the materials color names and bone names.

Is there a Find/Replace for names so I can delete all prefixes?
eg: Copy_HairColor => HairColor
eg: Character1_Hip   => Hip

Comment: I created and add-on for such situations: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-5

Answer (score 2):

You can try Proxe's addon here https://github.com/trentinfrederick/name-panel
and see if it will work for you. It is supposed to support batch renaming, so maybe that could work.

Edit: I will try to get some working examples in picture form tonight and update here.- craigo

[From the author, Trentin Frederick](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-5):

> **Summary**
>
> This add-on allows for batch naming operations and displays object datablock names in a single panel within the 3D view, don't take my word for it though, check it out
>
> The whole goal behind this add-on is to consolidate names and naming operations, while granting fast access to a few options here and there, I hope that this add-on saves you a lot of time.
>
> **Overview**
>
> This addon offers a panel that displays object related datablock names below the object and object data name fields, offering quick access within the 3D View to all available datablock names, along with an occasional option or few, like a mini outliner, filter options are located towards the top of the panel and the panel itself is located in the properties shelf of the 3D view and in addition this add-on comes with a series of operators that save a lot of time when renaming datablocks, the operators are as follows;
>
> **Auto Name**
>
> This operator allows for quickly naming objects and those object's modifiers, constraints, object data and for pose bones, bone constraints. It works by assigning names based on type, the names used are defined by the user and can be saved with user settings. (Options saved with the current scene)
>
> **Batch Name**
>
> This operator is the big work horse here, through its various toggle options and input fields you are able to perform find and replace text operations (with regular expression support) to almost all datablock names in the file and control how duplicate names will be numbered. The pop-up is a bit clustered but is fairly straightforward to understand once you use it a time or two, the tool-tips indicate what the option is doing/allowing.
>
> Note - This operator can be accessed either through the item panel special menu or in the outliner header, it can be called from any window type, just search 'batch'
>
> **Batch Name Copy**
>
> This operator is meant to fulfil the need to transfer names from some object datablocks to others, essentially copying them and pasting to the targets, this is done on a per object basis unless the 'use active object' option is active, which will then transfer the source name from the active object to the selected objects.
>
> WARNING! - By default all three operators DO NOTHING, you MUST activate the appropriate filters in the operator's pop-up
>
> If you have any questions, comments, concerns or suggestions; please reply to this thread.
>
> Please report any bugs either on this thread or github.
>
> WARNING AGAIN! - By default all three operators DO NOTHING, you MUST activate the appropriate filters in the operator's pop-up."
>
> [image]

Comment: Could you maybe explain how to use it a bit? Thanks!

Comment: I have seen that it installs now to the tool bar as a Name tab, and if you select all the objects you need to rename you can press the icon of the three stacked bars and there are operators for batch renaming, auto naming, etc. Choosing one will cause a panel to pop up that allows input for the new name, any suffix or prefix, and then other arguments. Pressing okay, I renamed 6 cubes as craigo.003-craigo.008 in a few seconds after installing. I think it is almost self explanatory, but proxe has a pretty good thread there of insight on what he is working on.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant as an edit to the answer. It's fantastic that there's a good thread over there, but we don't really like having link only answers here. The issue with them is that we can't guarantee that they'll stay up for forever. If for some reason BA went down, the addon would be referenced here but if anyone tried to learn about it, they couldn't because of the dead link. We'd rather have an explanation to go along with it, and maybe a direct download link.

Comment: Okay, I will see what I can do about that then.

Comment: Edited the first post answer to include a direct github link and the original description and illustration from the author's thread.

Comment: Fantastic, looks great. I'm going to quickly add in a link to the BA thread because you are quoting his post there. When quoting we it's nice to give a direct link to the source.

Comment: Okay, I thought I was on the right track this time - I'll learn :D

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.8 we now have "batch rename". Just go to Edit > Batch Rename

[image]